# Javascript angular parse queries synchronously (in sequence)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, promise

I am trying to use Parse in javascript to make two queries synchronously in sequence:

```
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
    innerQuery.equalTo("user_id",$localStorage.username);
    innerQuery.equalTo("status","confirmed")
    innerQuery.equalTo("code_verified",false)

    var innerQuerytrue = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
    innerQuerytrue.equalTo("user_id",$localStorage.username);
    innerQuerytrue.equalTo("status","confirmed")
    innerQuerytrue.equalTo("code_verified",true)


    innerQuery.find({}) 
    innerQuerytrue.find({}) 


    var eventDetails = []

    var queryfalse = new Parse.Query(Events)
    queryfalse.matchesKeyInQuery("id_event","event_id",innerQuery);

    var querytrue = new Parse.Query(Events)
    querytrue.matchesKeyInQuery("id_event","event_id",innerQuerytrue);


    queryfalse.find().then(function(results){
        for (var i in results) {
              var object = results[i];
              var eventId = object.get("id_event");
              var eventname = object.get("event_name");
              var datestart = object.get("date_start");
              var location = object.get("location");
              var eventimagefile = object.get("event_image");
              var eventimageurl = eventimagefile.url();
              eventDetails.push({'name':eventname,'eventId':eventId, 'location':location, 'datestart':datestart, 'eventphoto':eventimageurl,'verified':false})      
        }

    }).then(function(){
        querytrue.find().then(function(results1){
            for (var i in results1) {
                  var object = results1[i];
                  var eventId = object.get("id_event");
                  var eventname = object.get("event_name");
                  var datestart = object.get("date_start");
                  var location = object.get("location");
                  var eventimagefile = object.get("event_image");
                  var eventimageurl = eventimagefile.url();
                  eventDetails.push({'name':eventname,'eventId':eventId, 'location':location, 'datestart':datestart, 'eventphoto':eventimageurl,'verified':true})      
            }
        })

    }).then(function(){
        $scope.events = eventDetails;
    })
```

The second query, queryfalse, is not always executed. I am using promises and not sure if it is the right way to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the angular result to the 2nd promise.

```
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
    innerQuery.equalTo("user_id",$localStorage.username);
    innerQuery.equalTo("status","confirmed")
    innerQuery.equalTo("code_verified",false)

    var innerQuerytrue = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
    innerQuerytrue.equalTo("user_id",$localStorage.username);
    innerQuerytrue.equalTo("status","confirmed")
    innerQuerytrue.equalTo("code_verified",true)


    innerQuery.find({}) 
    innerQuerytrue.find({}) 


    var eventDetails = []

    var queryfalse = new Parse.Query(Events)
    queryfalse.matchesKeyInQuery("id_event","event_id",innerQuery);

    var querytrue = new Parse.Query(Events)
    querytrue.matchesKeyInQuery("id_event","event_id",innerQuerytrue);


    queryfalse.find().then(function(results){
        for (var i in results) {
              var object = results[i];
              var eventId = object.get("id_event");
              var eventname = object.get("event_name");
              var datestart = object.get("date_start");
              var location = object.get("location");
              var eventimagefile = object.get("event_image");
              var eventimageurl = eventimagefile.url();
              eventDetails.push({'name':eventname,'eventId':eventId, 'location':location, 'datestart':datestart, 'eventphoto':eventimageurl,'verified':false})      
        }

    }).then(function(){
        querytrue.find().then(function(results1){
            for (var i in results1) {
                  var object = results1[i];
                  var eventId = object.get("id_event");
                  var eventname = object.get("event_name");
                  var datestart = object.get("date_start");
                  var location = object.get("location");
                  var eventimagefile = object.get("event_image");
                  var eventimageurl = eventimagefile.url();
                  eventDetails.push({'name':eventname,'eventId':eventId, 'location':location, 'datestart':datestart, 'eventphoto':eventimageurl,'verified':true})      
            }
        }).then(function(){
            $scope.events = eventDetails;
        });
    })
```

Comment: Could he also add `return` in front of `querytrue.find().` and then leave that last `then()` where it was? I forget if that is valid syntax or not.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure actually.

Comment: @ai20 because `$scope.events` gets set after the `queryfalse` call and `querytrue` doesn't update it.

Comment: So should not the consecutive promises executed in sequence? I don't get why the last promise is executed before the second is finished.

Comment: @ai20, the last "then" is never given the promise so it executes immediately. See my answer for how to get the promise to that last "then" using your code structure.

Comment: querytrue.find() returns a promise immediately, the next 'then' is executed which updates $scope.events, and event details maybe does not have the results from querytrue yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `return` to pass the promise returned by `querytrue.find().then()` down the chain so the next `then()` won't execute until the promise is resolved. This also keeps your code flatter to avoid deeply nested promises.

```
    queryfalse.find().then(function(results){
        // code clipped for brevity
    }).then(function(){
        return querytrue.find().then(function(results1){
            // code clipped for brevity
        });
    }).then(function(){
        $scope.events = eventDetails;
    });
```

Here's a working plunker that demonstrates this: https://plnkr.co/edit/SwPIC1K6yEhEgpIlxoEo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

querytrue.find() -> returns a promise, and that promise eventually returns a list of results that you're interested in.

.then() sets up some action after a promise, and returns another promise immediately. You can also pass a success handler & error handler function

so, when you say

```
var p = querytrue.find().then(onSuccess, onError)
```

p is a promise that will become the return value of the success or failure function, whichever one runs. You can chain another promise by adding another .then()

This chained promise gets the return value of the first promise.

If the first promise success function ran, the second chained success one will also run, likewise with error functions.

If your success handler creates another promise (like your question), you can return that promise from the success handler, and any subsequent chained promises will wait for that promise. Sort of adding a link to the chain.

```
var p = query1.find(); 
p.then( function(){
   ... // runs after query1.find()
   var q = query2.find().then(...);
   return q; 
})
.then( function() { 
   ... // runs after query1.find() and query2.find()
});
```

Comment: you can also use a '.finally(' that only takes one function that will run no matter if a promise succeeds or fails, which may be what you're after

Comment: following your reasoning ('if the first promise success function ran, the second chained success one will also run,'..) I don't get why my code is wrong. After querytrue.find() , a promise with queryfalse.find() should be executed then another promise to assign the results. It does not happen in sequence. Why?

Comment: Try adding a failure handler to the 'then' statements. Very simply:

...then( function(){... } , function() { print "Error here"; } )